# Initialization warning after installing doom-modeline

Tags: init-file, package

So recently i decided to switch to Emacs (btw I am total noob) and began creating my init.el file
After downloading `doom-modeline` package from melpa and following it's installation guide I get an initialization warning:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/telman/.emacs.d/init.el’:
File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, doom-modeline
```

And this is my `init.el` setup:

```
(require 'package)
(require 'doom-modeline)
(doom-modeline-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
(load-theme 'dracula t)
(global-display-line-numbers-mode)
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(toggle-scroll-bar -1)
```

Comment: That warning says that he can't find the package doom-modeline. Can you try adding your site-lisp folder to the loadpath? eg. `(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/USER/.emacs.d/site-lisp")`

Comment: @Swedgin i don't have a site-lisp.Should i create one?

Comment: Try the answers first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `(require 'package)` and you shouldn't need to `(require 'doom-modeline)` either.  But, depending on your version of Emacs, you need to initialize the `package` library with `(package-initialize)` before you can use the packages you installed.

So my crystal ball tells me you should replace the first two lines of your `init.el` with

```
(package-initialize)
```

Comment: yeah.that was the case i replaced my "require" lines with (package-initialize) and added (doom-modeline-mode 1) after that

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to require a package which has not been installed yet.  Run

```
M-x package-install
```

and then specify

```
doom-modeline
```

This will install the package so that when you next start emacs, the error should no longer occur.